# How to precede a character Alphabetically?

Tags: java

Please tell me any method or logic to precede characters alphabetically (i.e., get the alphabetic predecessor of a character) eg. predecessor of a is b. I have searched the net but found nothing. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: what do you mean by "precede" ? also, is this specific to some encoding (ascii, utf-8, general unicode) or alphabet?

Comment: Your question doesnt makes sense. Can you please reformat your phrases and give some input and output expectation. Also let us know what have you tried so far?

Comment: This is much too vague. Please be more specific about what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: All characters have a numeric value.  (Cast a `char` to `int` and print it out to see.)  Standard Roman characters are in alphabetical order (Google "ASCII table").  So long as the alphabetic character is greater than "a" (or "A") you can subtract 1 to get the prior alphabetic character.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are asking how to get 'a' from 'b', it's quite simple :

```
char x = 'b';
x--;
System.out.println(x); // prints a
```